# Different methods to access value of an entry field in Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am using following simple code to change label text:

```
#! /usr/bin/wish8.6

label .a_lab -text "Enter text: "
entry .ent -textvariable tt
button .a_button -text "Change" -command changer

pack .a_lab -fill both -expand 1
pack .ent -fill both -expand 1
pack .a_button -fill both -expand 1

proc changer {} {
    .a_lab config -text $::tt ;# How can I access 'tt' using pathname '.ent'? 
    }

wm geometry . 300x200+300+300
```

Are there any other methods to access the value of 'tt' apart from '$::tt'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.ent get`.

The configure and cget subcommands to a widget are used to access a widget's own traits. The text content in an entry widget isn't intrinsic and shouldn't be accessed that way, but widgets often have a specific subcommand for any reasonable task one would want it to perform.

Note also that you can set both the label and the entry to use the same content variable, which gives you instant and automatic updates.

**ETA:** updating the label with processed content from the entry

Some widgets signal changes through a virtual event (`listbox` generates a `<<ListboxSelect>>` event, for instance). The `entry` widget doesn’t. To setup update triggers for the `entry` widget, you can:

1. bind the `<Return>` event to the entry widget: `bind .ent <Return> +mycallback`. This lets the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key trigger the update. The `+` can be omitted as there is no standard action for this event.
2. bind the `<Key>` event to the `Entry` class*: `bind Entry <Key> +mycallback`: any key will trigger an update, including editing keys. Note that if the event is bound to the widget, it fires *before* the keystroke edits the content of the entry. If you bind it to `Entry` but omit the `+`, the callback will be run *instead* of the usual action to edit the entry.
3. add a watching trace to the variable: `trace add variable tt write {apply {args mycallback}}`, or
4. hijack the validation mechanism: `.ent config -validate key -validatecommand {.a_lab config -text [string toupper %P];expr 1}`

The `mycallback` callback can be either

```
proc mycallback {} {
    .a_lab config -text [string toupper [.ent get]]
}
```

or

```
proc mycallback {} {
    .a_lab config -text [string toupper $::tt]
}
```

If you set the parameter list of the callback to `args`, you don't need to wrap it in `apply` when tracing. If you use the validation mechanism, read the docs so you know how it works (you should always do that, but it's really easy to get it wrong in confusing ways in this case).

Documentation:
[apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm),
[bind](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm),
[entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm),
[trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm)

---

*) i.e. X Window class, not OOP class.

Comment: Yes, `[.ent get]` works in place of `$::tt`. How can I arrange automatic updates with entered text made UPPERCASE (`string toupper [.ent get]`)?

Comment: @rnso: I have some suggestions for you now.

Comment: Great answer and suggestions. Thanks.